# Pandas create session number from log data

Tags: python, pandas, logging, timestamp

I have a log data with timestamp, userid ,action.

I would like to create a session ID based on the following rule:

If no action was done for 30 minutes by the user it should start a new session id for next action.

So for the following data frame :

| ts | userID | action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-23 00:01:19 | user1 | action1 |
| 2020-05-23 00:05:19 | user1 | action2 |
| 2020-05-23 00:35:19 | user1 | action3 |
| 2020-05-23 01:51:19 | user1 | action4 |
| 2020-05-23 00:01:19 | user2 | action1 |
| 2020-05-23 00:05:19 | user2 | action2 |
| 2020-05-23 00:35:19 | user2 | action3 |
| 2020-05-23 00:51:19 | user2 | action4 |

to the following

| ts | userID | action | SessionID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-23 00:01:19 | user1 | action1 | 1 |
| 2020-05-23 00:05:19 | user1 | action2 | 1 |
| 2020-05-23 00:15:19 | user1 | action3 | 1 |
| 2020-05-23 00:51:19 | user1 | action4 | 2 |
| 2020-05-23 00:01:19 | user2 | action1 | 1 |
| 2020-05-23 00:05:19 | user2 | action2 | 1 |
| 2020-05-23 00:35:19 | user2 | action3 | 1 |
| 2020-05-23 00:51:19 | user2 | action4 | 1 |

for user 1 a new sessionID is created because when the action was taken it has been more than 30 minutes since last record. but for user 2 there is no such gap

Thank in advance

Comment: You could try to *group by userID*: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html and then calculate differences of times between the row and the previous one using *.shift()* https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html and *datetime* package. Then you could mutate a new column saying that those differences longer than 30 minutes get previous row value (*shift* again) + 1. Sorry but I don't have enough time to make the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the dataframe by `userID` and for each group per `userID` calculate the [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) on timestamp column then compare the difference with timedelta of `30` minute to create a boolean mask finally use `cumsum` to create session ids per group

```
f = lambda t: t.diff().gt(pd.Timedelta('30T')).cumsum()
df['SessionID'] = df.groupby('userID')['ts'].apply(f) + 1
```

---

```
                   ts userID   action  SessionID
0 2020-05-23 00:01:19  user1  action1          1
1 2020-05-23 00:05:19  user1  action2          1
2 2020-05-23 00:35:19  user1  action3          1
3 2020-05-23 01:51:19  user1  action4          2
4 2020-05-23 00:01:19  user2  action1          1
5 2020-05-23 00:05:19  user2  action2          1
6 2020-05-23 00:35:19  user2  action3          1
7 2020-05-23 00:51:19  user2  action4          1
```