# Using pandas to create session id from log data based on time and user action

Tags: python, pandas, session, logging, timestamp

I have a log file of customer actions and no session ID, unfortunately. I would like to create a session ID based on three criteria:

- If no action for more than 5 minutes overall
- If no action for 30 seconds from the last action
- If *205# is a user request (user_req)

I have the following DataFrame:

| log_datetime | user_id | user_req |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/06/2022 08:51:29 | 776453448899 | *205# |
| 01/06/2022 08:51:29 | 776456362429 | *205# |
| 01/06/2022 08:51:29 | 776453448899 | 2 |
| 01/06/2022 08:51:30 | 776456362429 | 1 |
|  |  |  |
| 01/06/2022 09:11:15 | 776456362429 | 3 |
| 01/06/2022 09:11:15 | 776453448899 | *205# |
| 01/06/2022 09:11:15 | 776456362429 | 4 |
| 01/06/2022 09:11:15 | 776453448899 | 1 |
| 01/06/2022 09:11:15 | 776453448899 | 2 |
| 01/06/2022 09:11:16 | 776456362429 | 1 |
| 01/06/2022 09:11:16 | 776456362429 | 1 |

And add the session ID as follows:

| log_datetime | user_id | user_req | SessionID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/06/2022 08:51:29 | 776453448899 | *205# | 1 |
| 01/06/2022 08:51:29 | 776456362429 | *205# | 2 |
| 01/06/2022 08:51:29 | 776453448899 | 2 | 1 |
| 01/06/2022 08:51:30 | 776456362429 | 1 | 2 |
|  |  |  |  |
| 01/06/2022 09:11:15 | 776456362429 | 3 | 3 |
| 01/06/2022 09:11:15 | 776453448899 | *205# | 4 |
| 01/06/2022 09:11:15 | 776456362429 | 4 | 3 |
| 01/06/2022 09:11:15 | 776453448899 | 1 | 4 |
| 01/06/2022 09:11:15 | 776453448899 | 2 | 4 |
| 01/06/2022 09:11:16 | 776456362429 | 1 | 3 |
| 01/06/2022 09:11:16 | 776456362429 | 1 | 3 |

I tried using the information from the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324149/pandas-create-session-number-from-log-data) however without success.
This code also only addresses one of the time criteria:

```
f = lambda t: t.diff().gt(pd.Timedelta('5T')).cumsum()
df['SessionID'] = df.groupby('user_id')['log_datetime'].apply(f) + 1
```

I would truly appreciate any assistance in this regard, thank you.

Comment: What is a criteria for defining an `action`?

Comment: It is based on sequence of actions navigating through a menu. The *205# starts the menu.

Comment: Are you open to using numba based approach? This seems like a complex to problem to solve by just using builtin pandas method. Also can a session id repeat between different users?

Comment: Yes, very much open to that

Comment: Let me think of a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `pandas.DataFrame.resample`
Your condition is quite complex: You have multiple rules to be applied on multiple time intervals, in addition to a static rule: Why don't you downsample your time to 30-second intervals, to 5-minute intervals, and then you take your decision based on 3 conditions: what happened in the last 30 secs, in the last 5 min., and the req code (*205#)
The crux with samling is also: when does the 5-minute window start/end? Rolling 5 min. from every request? Or within 5 min. from the first of a number of requests..? Not sure your problem is 100% defined

Comment: yes the actual 5 minutes would start once the User Request of *205# starts.  The *205# user_req is the starting point for the session timmer. Once this is met the timer should start for 5 minutes or 30 seconds in that window with no user_req. I hope this clarifies the problem?